# Find the interval of a density

Tags: probability

Given the probability density function $(x+y)$ if $0 \leq x \leq y \leq c$, $0$ otherwise.

I want to calculate $c$. I clearly do not know at all where to start. I tried to take some integrals but I just do not know how to find the "limit" of the function.
 However, my math skills are not too advanced that is why I am not quite sure if there actually is some calculation involved.

I would appreciate some help, thanks.

Comment: "Density" meaning what? A probability density function?

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: "I looked at the graph and I think it is infinity" ?? Please explain.

Comment: Is $c$ the cube root of 6?

Comment: I am not sure. I do not evenknow how to start, I have never seen anything like this.

Answer (score 1):

A probability density function on $\mathbb R^2$ is a function $f:\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R$ that satisfies the following conditions:

- $f$ is measurable.
- $f$ only takes nonnegative values.
- $\int\int f(x,y)dxdy=1$

Especially the third condition gives you a way to calculate $c$. Note that in your case:$$\int\int f(x,y)dxdy=\int^c_0\int^y_0x+ydxdy$$

This results in an expression in $c$ that must take value $1$.

I leave the rest to you.